# How long can a healthy person stay in a dry sauna?

Tags: thermodynamics, biophysics

Inspired by the question how you can put your hand in the oven for a while (maybe forever), and an answer given to it by LLIaMnYP, I asked myself how long you can stay in a dry sauna (say with a temperature of 100 degrees Celsius).

Your skin takes in heat slowly (due to the low air heat conductivity), which is transferred to your inner body by your blood circulation) to the point you start to sweat. Sweat evaporates in high-temperature dry air, thereby cooling your skin and body. Like your body, also the sweat is slowly heated. Now the sweat (which has about the same heat conductivity as air) starts to heat up and again, heat is transferred to your body, via the skin and the blood circulation.

Is there more heat transferred *to* the body than extracted *from* the body by the evaporation of sweat? Or does an equilibrium develops?

Comment: I think standard saunas  go to roughly $80\,^\circ\mbox{C}$, and I remember being in there for up to 15 minutes or so. I think it's pretty clear that whatever the time is, it's finite (people have indeed died in saunas after having fallen asleep, I think), so I would assume that net heat transfer is positive.

Comment: What answer did you get, after asking yourself this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about human endurance, not physics.

Comment: @sammygerbil-When sitting without movement, I don't know the answer (though you have to drink  a lot of water), but we can replace the person by an equal (lifeless) mass (with the same heat conductivity and ratio between the volume and area as the person), with a device that transports the heat to the mass inside, and a cooling device that releases the same amount of heat from the machine as sweating  does.

Answer (score 1):

Experimentally, the answer is about 6 minutes, as tragically illustrated during the world sauna championship in 2010 (see Guardian paper [here](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2010/aug/08/sauna-championship-russian-dead)).

Comment: That may be a result, but it doesn't really answer the question: you'd need to dig more into how much water was in the the air. The fact that the guy had burns betokens very high humidity: latent heat of vaporization released when the water condenses on the body. You'd also need autopsy results: the guy may have had a an abnormal heart condition, and high vascular performance is a key part of this question.